# Как реализовать действие "открытия" аккордеона для innerHTML?

Tags: javascript, accordion

Реализация html-accordion выглядит так:

```
let acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");

for (let i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");

    let panel = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (panel.style.display === "block") {
      panel.style.display = "none";
    } else {
      panel.style.display = "block";
    }
  });
}
```

```
<div class="accordionPaper">
    <div>
          <button class="accordion">Section Demo</button>
          <div class="panel">
              <p>Hello, my name Tragislav</p>
              <button>Delete</button>
          </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
.accordion {
    background-color: #eee;
    color: #444;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 18px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    transition: 0.4s;
}

.active,
.accordion:hover {
    background-color: #ccc;
}

.panel {
    padding: 0 18px;
    background-color: white;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Но если я хочу создавать аккордеоны через

```
function addPaper(title, authors) {
        const element = document.createElement("div");

        element.innerHTML = `
        <button class="accordion">${title}</button>
        <div class="panel">
        <p>Authors: ${authors}</p>
        <button>Delete</button>
        </div>
        `;

        document.querySelector(".accordionPaper").append(element);
    }
```

Как мне реализовать "открытие" аккордеона для этой функции?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавить обработчик события не на элементы, а на их общего родителя. А при клике проверять, на кого кликнули. Если это искомый элемент - запустить функцию. Называется «Делегирование событий»

```js
let paper = document.querySelector(".accordionPaper");

paper.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  let accordion = e.target.closest(".accordion");
  if (!accordion) return; // Клик был не внутри аккордеона? Прервать функцию.
  
  let panel = accordion.nextElementSibling;
  let isVisible = (panel.style.display || getComputedStyle(panel).display) != "none";
  
  panel.style.display = isVisible ? "none" : "block";
});

/***/
addPaper(2, 222);
addPaper(3, 333);

function addPaper(title, authors) {
  const element = document.createElement("div");

  element.innerHTML = (`
    <button class="accordion">${ title }</button>
    <div class="panel">
      <p>Authors: ${ authors }</p>
      <button>Delete</button>
    </div>
  `);

  paper.append(element);
}
```

```css
.accordion {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 18px;
  margin: 2px 0;
  
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  
  text-align: left;
  transition: 0.4s;
  
  background-color: #eee;
  color: #444;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.accordion:hover {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.panel {
  display: none;
  padding: 0 18px;
  background-color: white;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="accordionPaper">
  <div>
    <button class="accordion">Bubu</button>
    <div class="panel">
      <p>Bubu</p>
      <button>Delete</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

`is_visible = (panel.style.display || getComputedStyle(panel).display) != "none";` — Если display определен в CSS, но не в HTML, `panel.style.display` вернет пустую строку (в логическом контексте — false), тогда сработает вторая часть выражения, которая даст реальное значение display.

Comment: Спасибо помогло!
Но появился ещё вопрос: как мне внутри этой конструкции на кнопку delete событие повешать?

Comment: @СтаниславДыкоменко Добавить еще один `paper.addEventListener("click", function(e) { if (!e.target.classList.contains("delete")) return;` // Дальше код удаления, где `e.target` - кнопка delete. Если таких "ветвлений" много, можно наоборот, сделать функцию обработки для каждого типа кнопки, а добавить только один listener, в котором через switch и classList / closest выбрать, какую функцию нужно вызвать.